# Android: how to make dialogs look the same on emulator / real phone

Tags: android, background, dialog

On my T-mobile MOVE, dialogs have black background and black text - not good.

On the emulator, all the dialogs have white background and black text.

How to fix this? Why is this happening? Am I supposed to explicitly set background for dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Royston said you have to make custom dialogs. To remove black corner use following line
    super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);

instead of making custom style.
A simple example of custom dialog will be like

```
public class customDialog extends Dialog implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

Context context = null;
    public customDialog(Context context, String etc ) {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        this.context = context;
        setBasicContents();
    }

    private void setBasicContents() {
        this.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        this.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok).setOnClickListener(this);
        this.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.img_bg_tranperant)).
        setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(166, 0, 0, 0));
    }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_ok:
                    anythingyouwant();
                    break;
                case R.id.btn_cancel:
                    this.dismiss();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
      }
}
```

A line

```
 ((RelativeLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout)).
            setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(166, 0, 0, 0));
```

is important. It take parent layout of dialog xml and set its background to little transparent. So when user see the dialog the back screen will little dim. In additon to this layout over dialog xml will contain two buttons and one textView to show message. You can customize this custom class and xml to your requirements.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you use default `Dialog` in Android, then since each vendor have set the colors and backgrounds for their dialogs, they will look different. For e.g. Samsung dialog is completely different from the default Nexus devices dialogs.

The best bet for you is to define your own colors and theme for dialogs to look uniform across all devices. Else brace yourself for a new look dialog as the vendor wants it to be displayed.

Comment: Do you know how I can easily define a uniform style for all of my dialogs? I tried a couple of background setting options inside the dialogs, but it was really painful (corners still remaining black, etc.) Any links are welcome.